# Make the `for` loop wait for each function to resolve

Tags: javascript

Page 1:

```
function tempWindow(text)
{
    var w = window.open('https://example.com/?data='+text, '_blank');
    var t = setInterval(() => {
        if(w.closed)
        {
            clearInterval(t);
            return true;
        }
    }, 100);
}

var list = ['text1', 'text2', 'text3'];

for(var i=0;i<list.length;i++)
{
    tempWindow(list[i]);//Each loop iteration must wait for each window to close
}
```

Temporary window:

```
(function(){
    setTimeout(() => {
        window.close();
    }, 5000);
})();
```

The code on page 1 should open three windows and send to each of them the strings `text1`, `text2`, `text3`, stored in the variable `data`.

These windows must not be opened at the same time. For this, `setInterval` checks every 100 milliseconds if the previous window has already been closed.

Therefore, the second window can only be opened after closing the first one and so on.

I believe that the `tempWindow` function could return a promise and that using `await` a solution would be possible, but I don't know how to do that.

Comment: try useing let or const instead so you will be able to debug this

Comment: You do not, you need to use a queue type of system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use that code. it will wait until window is close

```
function tempWindow(text) {
    return new Promise(resolve => {
        var w = window.open('https://example.com/?data=' + text, '_blank');
        var t = setInterval(() => {
            if (w.closed) {
                clearInterval(t);
                resolve(true);
            }
        }, 100);
    })
}

var list = ['text1', 'text2', 'text3'];

for (var i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
    await tempWindow(list[i]);//Each loop iteration must wait for each window to close
}
```

make sure loop code is inside async function like that

```
async testFunction(){
    var list = ['text1', 'text2', 'text3'];

for (var i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
    await tempWindow(list[i]);//Each loop iteration must wait for each window to close
}
}
```

call function like this `testFunction()`

Comment: Sorted out! Thanks